# How to import library which is not module in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

How to import in the webpack third party library which is not module (ES, CJS, AMD, etc.)?

For example external library is just an object:

```
var libObj = {
  a: "a",
  getAddress: function() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

But how to import this in root JS file? For example in main.js:

```
import ...what... from ...where...
```

Comment: you need to export something to import it

Comment: @Luca ok, but if library is not mine? Just external downloaded so what then?

Comment: Include it as a script element before the code you need this to work with

Comment: @Luca Yeah but I still want use webpack to this becaue I want one file with all js files. What about ProvidePlugin? Would have worked?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `exports-loader`:

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            /* ... */
            {
                test: require.resolve('ye-olde-lib.js'),
                use: 'exports-loader?libObj'
            },
            /* ... */
        ]
    }
};
```

It's covered in official documentation: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#global-exports

Answer (score 0):

You need to first export your `libObj` file:

```js
// your libObj.js file

var libObj = {
  a: "a",
  getAddress: function() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default libObj;

// your webpack file

import libObj from './libObj.js'

//.. do things
```

Comment: Ok, but it is not my library :P it's an external library but not from NPM, just downloaded and it's just an object. So should I edit this library adding export?

Comment: I would suggest so. Although, It's not such a good idea to download a library like this.. it will be a mess when you'd want to upgrade the version later

Answer (score 0):

In your library write `export default libObj` (ES6).
And in your JS file `import <yourFavoriteVarName> from '<pathToLib>'`;

Comment: It's clearly not a good practice. You can't just rely on this as the library is managed by a package manager in this workflow, so you'll loose your lib. code update in the next package update.

Comment: In general you are right, but in this case, it seems there is no version control behind the given third-party lib. So you would have to take care about updates manually anyway.

Comment: Yes in that case, okay.